# Find $x$ and $y$ for $e^y+ye^x=0$, $xe^y+e^x=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

By looking at the equations it becomes obvious that the solution is $-1$ for $x$ and $y$. But how can I show that?

1. $e^y+ye^x=0$
2. $xe^y+e^x=0$

Answer (score 1):

Multiply the first equation by $x$ and subtract from the second. It follows that $xy=1$. Hence the first equation gives $e^{1/x}=-\frac 1 x e^{x}$ or $e^{\frac 1 x-x} +\frac 1 x=0$. Check that the derivative of the left side is negative. Hence the function can vanish at atmost one point. Since it does vanish at $x=-1$ it follows that $x=y=-1$ is the only possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

$$ey+ye^x =y(e+e^x)=0\Rightarrow y=0$$
Then
$$xe^y+e^x=x+e^x=0\Rightarrow x=-W(1)$$
where $ W()$ is the Lambert W function

EDIT: This is an answer to the equations in the text of your question, I now see that your title has a different question, and people in the comments doubt as well on what your question really is.